# SpriteKit: Uniform Circular Motion

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode

I'm trying to move a sprite in a circular motion using a reusable function (that I need to use on different objects).

The first result is given by this function:

```
func circularMotion(angle: CGFloat, radius: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGPoint{
    let x = radius * cos(angle) + center.x
    let y = radius * sin(angle) + center.y
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```

And then I update the position of my sprite like this:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
player.position = circularMotion(ang, radius: 200, center: CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2))

ang += speed
}
```

Where `ang` (the angle) and `speed` (0.05) are two initialized properties.

And this works pretty fine, but the actual problem is that I need to have the velocity of the sprite that rotates, since it has a `PhysicBody`.

My approach, though, changes only the position of the sprite. So I decided to do something like this:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

let prevCirc = circularMotion(ang, radius: 200, center: CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2))

let Circ = circularMotion(ang + 0.05, radius: 200, center: CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2))

let v = CGVector(dx: Circ.x - prevCirc.x, dy: Circ.y - prevCirc.y )

player.physicsBody!.velocity = v
}
```

I just calculated the difference of position, finding the perpendicular Vector respect to the position vector. This still "works", the body follows a circular motion, but it has not the radius and center given (it's a smaller circle).

I know it's because of the length of the vector that it gives this result.

So the real question is, having the radius and the center of the circle I want (and the speed of how the angle changes) how can I calculate the perpendicular velocity so that it gives me a motion with those properties?

Comment: Try avoiding opinion based questions here on SO,  keep your questions simple, just show what work you have done to create the orbit,  and ask how to go about making it work.  Then the community will share ways to make it happen, and you pick whatever you feel is best to get it to work.  After you do get it working,  take it over to codereview.stackexchange.com, and the folks there will give it a look over and offer best practice advice.

Comment: before moving on elliptic orbit, I decided to simplify the work and start with circluar motion, then I will move to elliptic. As asked I tried to show the work done. Thanks for advice @Knight0fDragon